# Stretches or exercise to to able to sit with knees together?

Tags: stretching, mobility

This is the opposite of asking how to sit cross legged.

Years of poor posture and crossing my legs have left me unable to sit with my knees together for longer then a few seconds, after a few seconds my legs begin to tremble and i have to force them together, which in turn increases the trembling and starts hurting. The trembling can be pretty embarrassing in public transit or venues without wide seats.

This leads to my 2 options being man-spreading or finding weird ways to sit cross-legged no matter how awkward. This doesn't seem to be a common problem because google results tend to be about how to sit cross legged (there seemed to be a few Reddit posts, but i blocked Reddit because its awful for productivity and sanity.)

Solutions I've thought about.

1. Tying my thighs together with a belt to force my legs closer and ignore the pain/trembling.
2. Giving up and just sitting half lotus everywhere.
3. Standing desk? (Doesn't really help in cars or long public transit rides)
4. Accepting that I have to man spread if i want to sit in public.

I've tried looking at common stretches and yoga poses but they all seem more geared towards increases in mobility of the hips outwards and not inwards.

Comment: Can you pinpoint what part of the leg the trembling is coming from? Quads, hamstrings, inner thighs? Also, how large are your thighs? When you sit with knees together, does this squish your thighs against each other, such that they're pushing each other out?

Comment: @DavidScarlett seems to come from the area between the femur and pelvis, my thighs are large so there is squishing, but it doesn't really feel like they are pushing each other.

Comment: How extreme is the spread? I know my legs naturally have about a fist of length between them at the knees. And honestly, I don't know that I've every tried keeping them tightly closed for long periods of time. I do habitually cross my legs in what I'm told is the European manner for men, crossing knee over knee.

Comment: @SeanDuggan The trembling starts with like 2 and a half fists of space. Which doesnt seem normal.

Comment: Possibly something like the shin box would help? https://www.stack.com/a/unlock-tight-hips/